# How does GetLastActivePopup work?

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to apply the techniques of GetLastActivePopup.

I was wondering how does GetLastAcitvePopup work? Is there like a window property or something it checks?

Does anyone know where I can find the SourceCode of this function? THat would help me a lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each window in the system has an internal, non-public, non-documented, data structure and one of the fields in that data structure is used to keep track of its last active popup's `HWND`.

Seeing the source code of the `GetLastActivePopup` function would not be very enlightening since all it would do is return the value of that data field.

Whenever a new window is activated, Windows looks to see if it has an owner (and if that owner has an owner, and so on). If so it then records the newly activated window as that owner's last active popup.

Comment: Thanks man! My issue was, using GetTopWindow and GetNextWindow I got the highest z ordered non-minimized window, and then the highest z ordered minizmied window. Now i need to identify which of the two was last active. Can you please link me to this data structure so I can accomplish this. Or if u can just give me its name. I found a super place for undocumented strcutures its processhacker http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/struct___s_y_s_t_e_m___h_a_n_d_l_e___t_a_b_l_e___e_n_t_r_y___i_n_f_o.html

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood you, `GetLastActivePopup` wouldn't help because it only tracks **owned** windows (i.e. those that are owned by another top-level window), and it sounds like you want a general "which window was last active in the whole system".

Comment: Possibly you could implement a global hook to track `WM_ACTIVATE/WM_ACTIVATEAPP`

Comment: I'm trying to avoid implementing that hook @user1793036 :( Yes you're right JonathanPotter that GetLastActivePopup won't work but I was thinking if I looked at the structure i could find something like "minimized time" or something. I just need to determine which of the 2 `HWND`s I have was more recently activated, the minimized one, or the non-minimized one. I just did some awesome stuff with undocumented stuff so I'm thinking the undocumented structure holds some magic too. :)

Comment: I found some window properties like `OleEndPointID` and `OleDropTargetInterface` and `ManageWindowInfoProperty` and `MozilliansWidgetPtr#####` on my firefox windows, im hoping maybe i could use some property to determine which of the two handles is more recent.

Comment: @Noitidart: The internal WND structure is stored in kernel memory, and mapped read-only into user space. You'd need to reverse engineer the internal `ValidateHwnd` function, to understand how to retrieve the user space memory address from a `HWND` value. See [this Under The Hood article](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0397/hood/hood0397.aspx) for details. In all, its not worth it. You have opted for the wrong solution long ago. I'd recommend letting go.

Comment: Thanks @IInspectable man for the info and stuff :) Ill just focus the HWND of the first one that comes up based on zorder then what do you think? Ill give that article a read and see what I can find on ValidateHwnd real quick though, thanks for that info! :)

Comment: Holy heck I just used the GetNextWindow and GetWindow thing and only testing GetWindowLong for visible. And even if minimized the hwnd shows up before the maximized window. So that works just like get most recent window! Is this expected behavior? thx all!!